# Compare if a var is Hex or RGBA in Sass

Tags: css, sass

I have a variable that can either be a hex or rgba value and I need a way to guarantee that the **var prints out as a rgba in css**.

```
var $color: #000 || rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
```

I've looked at rgba($color, 1) but this prints out a hex value if the opacity is 1 and this is can only be used if I know the value is in hex.

How can I accomplish this with sass?

Comment: can you get by with `rgba($color,0.999)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can accept a very slight opacity, the following appears to work:

```
color: if(rgba($color,1) == $color, rgba($color,0.99), $color);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm able to get the code working with it. : ) Although still trying to find a way to get it with exactly 1 opacity.

Comment: Just wanted to update that I had been able to achieve what I needed to do with a workaround that lets me use a hex value in the css. Although the answer is outside the question, just wanted to let people know.